# How to get Coordinates from zipCode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

i am trying to fetch coordinates from zipcode,but getting error

> {
>       "error_message" = "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address
>   0.0.0.0., with empty referer";
>       results =     (
>       );
>       status = "REQUEST_DENIED"; }

Here is my code :

```
public func getLocationFromAddress(zipCode : String) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let lat : Double = 0.0
    let lon : Double = 0.0        
    let strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(zipCode)&key=\(Global.kGoogleApiKey.strPlaceAPIKey)&sensor=false"
    let escapedString = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    AFAPIMaster.sharedAPIMaster.getLatLongCallApi_Completion(strGetURL:escapedString!,params: nil, showLoader: true, enableInteraction: false, viewObj:self.view, onSuccess: { (result) in
      if let Dict = result as? NSDictionary {
        print(Dict)
      }
    }, onFailure: { })
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
}
```

Comment: The API key that you are using does not work

Comment: i have to create  server key?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Api_key for your mobile application with bundle id to be able to use that geocoding

Comment: How to create server key

Comment: asking for billing